# Android: Programatically remove a specific checkbox

Tags: java, android

I want to programmatically add checkboxes into a view when I press a button and when the checkbox is checked I want that specific checkbox to be removed.

```
    Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_btnAdd);
    final EditText edtHomework = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_edtHomework);
    final LinearLayout llHomework = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_llHomework);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cbHomework = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);
            cbHomework.setText("• " + edtHomework.getText().toString());
            llHomework.addView(cbHomework);
            edtHomework.setText("");
        }
    });

    cbHomework.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (cbHomework.isChecked()){
                // remove the checkbox that is ticked
            }
        }
    });
```

For example, I have a list of things to complete:
[image: List of things I must complete]

If it is ticked (like Physics), I want it to be removed.

Comment: Did you try to just hide the views. checkedCheckbox.setVisibility(GONE)

Comment: @AdityaDesai The problem is I need to find which check is checked

Comment: did you try using a OnCheckedChangedListener on your checkbox?

Comment: @merge_conflict see my (edited) answer.

Comment: @nabillondon works perfectly now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set OnCheckedChangedListener right after creating and adding the checkbox, like this:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cbHomework = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);
        cbHomework.setText(edtHomework.getText().toString());
        llHomework.addView(cbHomework);

        cbHomework.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked)
                        llHomework.removeView(compoundButton);
                }
            });
    }
});
```